# Backbone.js - error event not fired when saving an object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a Backbone Model with validation logic. I have bound the following method to show the field errors when the validation fails:

`this.model.on('error', this.showError);`

When I try to **set** invalid values to my model, the *error* event is getting fired properly.

`this.model.set(invalidValues); // triggers showError method`

But if I try to **save** the object using the same invalid values, the validation fails as expected, but the *error* event is not getting fired, hence the *showError* method is not getting called..

`this.save(invalidValues, {error:this.failed,success:this.succeeded}); // does not trigger showError`

The **save** does not trigger the *error* event, but the *this.failed* is getting called as expected.

So, what do I need to do to make sure the that the *on error* event is always triggered when there's a validation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the error callback in your save options it overrides the default of backbone, which is to trigger the error event.  In your error callback, you can trigger the error event on the model or just call your showError method.